# What is the thing I'm trying to do called?

Tags: parsing

I think there must be a name for whatever it is I'm trying to do. I want to have a list of... requests and what the responses should look like. But the different requests and responses are not formatted the same. They are simple strings, so here's some examples:

```
request => response
foo%% => "OK" 
foo? => "%%"
%%%%bar => "OK"  
Version? => "Baz-%%%%"
```

Where % could be a number or letter.

I can code for each possible command with a big switch/case, but I wanted to make it more extend-able and maybe testable. Sorry this question is so vague. Please rename it and/or tag it correctly.

I'm doing this in javascript/node if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're inventing but it sounds like regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You would call `%` a wildcard in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will need parse the input to verify syntactic correctness and output a data structure that represents the input. Then you will need to analyze your intermediate data structure to determine semantics. The simplest way would be to use objects that implement a common interface.

```
object FooRequest (value)
    implements Request
    method Process ()
        return "OK"
```